UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined using nest typescript
I’m experiencing an issue while trying to upload my TypeScript NestJS application to AWS as an API.This API working before but after update get this error I encountered the following error in the AWS logs:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

how to troubleshoot and fix this error? I’m a beginner, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
error from aws web.stdout.log
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: (node:25450) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at ResourceCacheService.refreshStudyAndConsultation (/var/app/current/src/resource/service/resource.cache.ts:314:97)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at ResourceCacheService.refreshCachePublicFacing (/var/app/current/src/resource/service/resource.cache.ts:98:5)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at ResourceCacheService.onModuleInit (/var/app/current/src/resource/service/resource.cache.ts:82:5)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at async Promise.all (index 0)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at Object.callModuleInitHook (/var/app/current/node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-module-init.hook.js:43:5)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at NestApplication.callInitHook (/var/app/current/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.js:169:13)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at NestApplication.init (/var/app/current/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:97:9)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at NestApplication.listen (/var/app/current/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:156:33)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: (node:25450) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 61)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: (node:25450) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

the code from resource.cache
@Injectable()
export class ResourceCacheService implements OnModuleInit {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(ResourceCacheService.name);
  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache,
    @InjectModel("resource") private readonly model: Model<Resource, ResourceKey>,
    private readonly infoService: InfoCache,
    private readonly categoryService: CategoryCacheService
  ) {}

  public async find(type: ResourceType, subType: string): Promise<Resource[]> {
    return await this.cacheManager.get(this.getKey(type, subType));
  }

  public async getAlf() {
    return await this.cacheManager.get(this.getKeyPublic(ALF));
  }

  public async getContact() {
    return await this.cacheManager.get(this.getKeyPublic(CONTACT));
  }

  public async getHomepage() {
    return await this.cacheManager.get(this.getKeyPublic(HOMEPAGE));
  }

  public async getManagement() {
    return await this.cacheManager.get(this.getKeyPublic(MANAGEMENT));
  }

  public async getMembership() {
    return await this.cacheManager.get(this.getKeyPublic(MEMBERSHIP));
  }

  public async getStudyAndConsultation() {
    return await this.cacheManager.get(this.getKeyPublic(STUDY_AND_CONSULTATION));
  }

  public async getTraining() {
    return await this.cacheManager.get(this.getKeyPublic(TRAINING));
  }

  public async getHistory() {
    return await this.cacheManager.get(this.getKeyPublic(HISTORY));
  }

  public async getVisionMission() {
    return await this.cacheManager.get(this.getKeyPublic(VISION_MISSION));
  }

  public async getLoginPage() {
    return await this.cacheManager.get(this.getKeyPublic(LOGIN));
  }

  public async onModuleInit() {
    await this.refreshCacheInternal();
    await this.refreshCachePublicFacing();
  }

  @Interval(CACHE_REFRESH_INTERVAL())
  public refreshCache() {
    this.refreshCacheInternal();
    this.refreshCachePublicFacing();
  }

  private async refreshCachePublicFacing() {
    await this.refreshAlf();
    await this.refreshContact();
    await this.refreshHistory();
    await this.refreshHomepage();
    await this.refreshManagement();
    await this.refreshMembership();
    await this.refreshStudyAndConsultation();
    await this.refreshTraining();
    await this.refreshVisionMission();
    await this.refreshLoginPage();
  }

  private async refreshCacheInternal() {
    let start = moment();
    this.logger.log(`Start refresh cache`);
    for (let type of ResourceTypeArray) {
      let dataList = await this.model.query("type").eq(type).exec();

      let subTypeList = dataList.map((e) => e.subType);
      for (let subType of subTypeList) {
        let dataSubType = await dataList.filter((e) => e.subType == subType);
        await this.cacheManager.set(this.getKey(type, subType), dataSubType);
      }
    }
    this.logger.log(`Finish refresh cache ${moment().diff(start, "millisecond")}ms`);
  }

  private getKey(type: any, subType: any) {
    return `RESOURCE.${type}.${subType}`;
  }

  private getKeyPublic(type: any) {
    return `RESOURCE.PUBLIC.${type}`;
  }

  private async refreshContact() {
    let type = ResourceType.Contact;
    let subType = ResourceSubType.Contact;
    let cachedData = {
      address: (await this.find(type, subType.Address))[0].content,
      email: (await this.find(type, subType.Email))[0].content,
      fax: (await this.find(type, subType.Fax))[0].content,
      phone: (await this.find(type, subType.Phone))[0].content,
      companyCatalog: (await this.find(type, subType.CompanyCatalog))[0].url,
      socialMedia: (await this.find(type, subType.SocialMedia)).map((e) => {
        return {
          platformName: e.title,
          accountName: e.content,
        };
      }),
    };
    this.cacheManager.set(this.getKeyPublic(CONTACT), cachedData);
  }

  private async refreshHomepage() {
    let type = ResourceType.Homepage;
    let subType = ResourceSubType.Homepage;

    let carrousel = await this.find(type, subType.Carousel);
    // let newProduct = await this.find(type, subType.NewProduct);
    let ourStrength = await this.find(type, subType.OurStrength);
    let ourFocus = await this.find(type, subType.OurFocus);
    let testimoni = await this.find(type, subType.Testimoni);

    let cachedData = {
      banner: (await this.find(type, subType.Banner))[0].url,
      carousel: carrousel
        ? await Promise.all(
            carrousel?.map(async (e) => {
              let originInfo: InfoCacheById = (await this.infoService.findById(e.otherData.originId)) as InfoCacheById;

              return {
                title: e.title,
                content: e.content,
                imageUrl: originInfo.headerUrl,
                linkTo: originInfo.queryKey,
                section: e.otherData.section,
              };
            })
          )
        : [],
      ourStrength: ourStrength?.map((e) => {
        return {
          title: e.title,
          content: e.content,
          icon: e.url,
        };
      }),
      ourFocus: ourFocus?.map((e) => {
        return {
          title: e.title,
          content: e.content,
          icon: e.url,
        };
      }),
      testimoni: testimoni?.map((e) => {
        return {
          name: e.title,
          position: e.otherData.position,
          content: e.content,
        };
      }),
      // newProduct: newProduct?.map((e) => {
      //   return {
      //     name: e.title,
      //     linkTo: e.otherData.linkTo,
      //     content: e.content,
      //   };
      // }),
    };
    this.cacheManager.set(this.getKeyPublic(HOMEPAGE), cachedData);
  }

  private async refreshHistory() {
    let type = ResourceType.AboutUs;
    let subType = ResourceSubType.AboutUs;
    let cachedData = {
      history: (await this.find(type, subType.History))[0].content,
      historyImage: (await this.find(type, subType.History))[0].url,
      founders: (await this.find(type, subType.HistoryFounder)).map((e) => {
        return {
          name: e.title,
          position: e.content,
          photo: e.url,
        };
      }),
      quickLinks: await this.categoryService.findByPageName(QuickLinkPageName.History),
    };
    this.cacheManager.set(this.getKeyPublic(HISTORY), cachedData);
  }

  async refreshVisionMission() {
    let type = ResourceType.AboutUs;
    let subType = ResourceSubType.AboutUs;
    let cachedData = {
      vision: (await this.find(type, subType.Vision))[0].content,
      mission: (await this.find(type, subType.Mission)).map((e) => {
        return {
          content: e.content,
          icon: e.url,
        };
      }),
      colorPhilosophy: {
        image: (await this.find(type, subType.LogoColorPhilosophyImage))?.[0].url,
        description: (await this.find(type, subType.LogoColorPhilosophyDescription))?.[0].content,
        detail: (await this.find(type, subType.LogoColorPhilosophyDetailDescription))?.map((e) => {
          return {
            text: e.title,
            color: e.content,
          };
        }),
      },
      symbolPhilosophy: {
        image: (await this.find(type, subType.LogoSymbolPhilosophyImage))?.[0].url,
        description: (await this.find(type, subType.LogoSymbolPhilosophyDescription))?.[0].content,
        detail: (await this.find(type, subType.LogoSymbolPhilosophyDetailDescription))?.map((e) => {
          return {
            text: e.title,
            color: e.content,
          };
        }),
      },
      quickLinks: await this.categoryService.findByPageName(QuickLinkPageName.VisionMission),
    };
    this.cacheManager.set(this.getKeyPublic(VISION_MISSION), cachedData);
  }

  private async refreshManagement() {
    let type = ResourceType.AboutUs;
    let subType = ResourceSubType.AboutUs;
    let sortedManagement = (await this.find(type, subType.Management)).sort(CommonUtil.dynamicSort("createdAt"));
    let cachedData = {
      management: (await sortedManagement).map((e) => {
        return {
          name: e.title,
          content: e.content,
          photo: e.url,
          position: e.otherData.position,
        };
      }),
    };
    this.cacheManager.set(this.getKeyPublic(MANAGEMENT), cachedData);
  }

  private async refreshAlf() {
    let type = ResourceType.AboutUs;
    let subType = ResourceSubType.AboutUs;
    let cachedData = {
      description: (await this.find(type, subType.AstagatraLeadersForumDesc))[0].content,
      astagatraLeadersForum: (await this.find(type, subType.AstagatraLeadersForum)).map((e) => {
        return {
          name: e.title,
          content: e.content,
          photo: e.url,
          position: e.otherData.position,
        };
      }),
      quickLinks: await this.categoryService.findByPageName(QuickLinkPageName.AstagatraLeadersForum),
    };
    this.cacheManager.set(this.getKeyPublic(ALF), cachedData);
  }

  private async refreshMembership() {
    let type = ResourceType.AboutUs;
    let subType = ResourceSubType.AboutUs;
    let cachedData = {
      description: (await this.find(type, subType.MembershipDesc))[0].content,
      benefit: (await this.find(type, subType.MembershipBenefit))[0].content,
      quickLinks: await this.categoryService.findByPageName(QuickLinkPageName.Membership),
    };
    this.cacheManager.set(this.getKeyPublic(MEMBERSHIP), cachedData);
  }

  private async refreshStudyAndConsultation() {
    let type = ResourceType.Service;
    let subType = ResourceSubType.Service;
    let advisoryBenefit = (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationAdvisoryBenefit))[0];
    let strategicBenefit = (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationStrategicBenefit))[0];

    let cachedData = {
      catalog: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultation))[0].url,
      mainPicture: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationMainPicture))[0].url,
      catalogMainPicture:(await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationCatalogMainPicture))[0].url,
      mainDesc: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationMainDesc))[0].content,
      whyUsDesc: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationWhyUsDesc))[0].content,
      methodDesc: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationMethodDesc))[0].content,
      methodItem: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationMethodItem)).map((e) => {
        return {
          content: e.content,
          title: e.title,
        };
      }),
      quickLinks: await this.categoryService.findByPageName(QuickLinkPageName.StudyAndConsultation),

      advisoryBenefit: {
        content: advisoryBenefit.content,
        icon: advisoryBenefit.url,
      },
      advisoryDesc: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationAdvisoryDesc))[0].content,
      advisoryItem: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationAdvisoryItem)).map((e) => {
        return {
          content: e.content,
          title: e.title,
        };
      }),

      strategicBenefit: {
        content: strategicBenefit.content,
        icon: strategicBenefit.url,
      },
      strategicDesc: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationStrategicDesc))[0].content,
      strategicItem: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationStrategicItem)).map((e) => {
        return {
          content: e.content,
          title: e.title,
        };
      }),
    };
    this.cacheManager.set(this.getKeyPublic(STUDY_AND_CONSULTATION), cachedData);
  }

  private async refreshTraining() {
    let type = ResourceType.Service;
    let subType = ResourceSubType.Service;

    let cachedData = {
      catalog: (await this.find(type, subType.Training))[0].url,
      mainPicture: (await this.find(type, subType.TrainingMainPicture))[0].url,
      mainDesc: (await this.find(type, subType.TrainingMainDesc))[0].content,
      item: (await this.find(type, subType.TrainingItem)).map((e) => {
        return {
          content: e.content,
          title: e.title,
        };
      }),
      method: (await this.find(type, subType.TrainingMethod)).map((e) => {
        return {
          url: e.url,
          title: e.title,
        };
      }),
      quickLinks: await this.categoryService.findByPageName(QuickLinkPageName.Training),
    };
    this.cacheManager.set(this.getKeyPublic(TRAINING), cachedData);
  }

  private async refreshLoginPage() {
    let type = ResourceType.Login;
    let subType = ResourceSubType.Login;

    let cachedData = {
      banner: (await this.find(type, subType.LoginImage))?.[0].url,
    };
    this.cacheManager.set(this.getKeyPublic(LOGIN), cachedData);
  }
}


The problem is one of the [0] lines in your refreshStudyAndConsultation function. Which is line 314 of resource.cache.ts? That's the line causing your error probably because whatever you're trying to find() does not exist

@Phil is there a way to solve it, ah ok i take down the image

Yes, debug the issue. Start at the line causing the error and work back from there
